# How to use function name as parameter?

Tags: c++, function, parameters

I tried to pass function name as parameter as below:

```
class RemoteControlMonitor {
private:
    void (*rph)(unsigned int key);
    void (*rrh)(unsigned int key);

public:
    RemoteControlMonitor(void (*pressed)(unsigned int key), 
                     void (*released)(unsigned int key) = 0) {
     *rph = pressed;
     *rrh = released;
     lr_set_handler(remote_control_handler);
    }

    void runPressed() {
     while (!shutdown_requested()) {
         remote_key = 0;
         remote_etype = 0;
         wait_event(&remote_control_pressed, 0);

             if (*rph) {
                 (*rph)(remote_key);
             }
         }
     }
 };
```

when I compile it, the error is as below, what can I do?

RemoteControlMonitor.H: In method `RemoteControlMonitor::RemoteControlMonitor(void (*)(unsigned int), void (*)(unsigned int) = 0)':

RemoteControlMonitor.H:61: assignment of read-only location

RemoteControlMonitor.H:61: assignment to `void ()(unsigned int)' from`void (*)(unsigned int)'

RemoteControlMonitor.H:62: assignment of read-only location

RemoteControlMonitor.H:62: assignment to `void ()(unsigned int)' from`void (*)(unsigned int)'

Comment: `*rph = pressed` => `rph = pressed` (lose the star).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to use typedef it will be more clear.

```
typedef  void (*keyaction)(unsigned int key);

class RemoteControlMonitor {
private:
    keyaction rph;
    keyaction rrh;

public:
    RemoteControlMonitor(keyaction pressed, 
                     keyaction released = NULL) {
     rph = pressed;
     rrh = released;
     lr_set_handler(remote_control_handler);
    }

    void runPressed() {
     while (!shutdown_requested()) {
         remote_key = 0;
         remote_etype = 0;
         wait_event(&remote_control_pressed, 0);

             if (rph) {
                 (*rph)(remote_key);
             }
         }
     }
 };
```

**EDIT:**

**this function goes to constructor:**

```
void f(unsigned int){}
```

**you declare it like this:**

```
RemoteControlMonitor  rcm(f);
```

Comment: RemoteControlMonitor.H:58: invalid type `void *' for default argument to `void (*)(unsigned int)'

Comment: Then I call it with function void my_remote_pressed(unsigned int key) {….} by rcm = new RemoteControlMonitor(&my_remote_pressed); compile error is In function `int main(int, char **)':
ANSI C++ forbids implicit conversion from `void *' in default argument

Comment: Follow your code, I did it as below:
void my_remote_pressed(unsigned int key) {
…
}

RemoteControlMonitor rcm(my_remote_pressed);

int runRCM(int argc, char **argv) {
 rcm.runPressed();
 return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
 execi(&runRCM, 0, 0, PRIO_NORMAL + 1, DEFAULT_STACK_SIZE);
 return 0;
}
The error is 
RemoteControlMonitor.H:58: invalid type `void *' for default argument to `void (*)(unsigned int)'
rcx1.C: In function `void __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
rcx1.C:54: ANSI C++ forbids implicit conversion from `void *' in default argument
What can I do next?

Comment: which line is 58? I guess you you can try to cast the NULL. (keyaction)NULL

Answer (score 2):

you do not need to dereference you pointer, `*rph`, just call it as normal as `rph` and it should work fine, other wise you are trying to set the pointer `*rph` to pressed and not its value.

The `*rph = pressed` means set my memory location to `pressed`, where `rph = pressed` means set my value to `pressed`.

[This](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/) link has some handy information in regards to references, pointers and dereferencing.

Hope this helps:)